# DNS not resolving and means API is failing when connecting to site

Tags: dns

I changed the DNS details for my websites to new nameservers, however I realised these were incorrect (after 24 hours). So they were changed to correct values. The sites are now slowly beginning to resolve through different ISPs.

The problem I have is that one website uses the data from another via an API and this is now broken. Is there a way to force it to use the correct details? For example would it be correct to add the IPs to the hosts file?

Comment: can the server your website is hosted on ping the 'data' server? Maybe the new DNS server cannot resolve it?

Comment: @MarcCostello nope, I get the following: "ping: cannot resolve example.com: Host name lookup failure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work, unless the other end performs reverse lookups. If that is the case then settings would need to be changed on both sides, assuming you have control over the other server.

If it performs reverse lookups and you have no control over the second server, then you just have to wait for the public records to update.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm going to have to wait :/